# Laravel 5 Carbon global Locale

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to set the same global locale of laravel which is :

```
config('app.locale')
```

to work with Carbon.

It seems like you can do it by using either :

```
Carbon::setLocale('fr')
```

or

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'theLocale');
```

So I have tried using middleware or providers but was not successful.

(why is this not a default feature of laravel?)

Comment: What is/was the problem? Did you get any error or does it just not work?
What have you done for debug? dump the getLocale, config and so on output?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So this is my bad, Carbon is actually using the php

```
setlocale();
```

the

```
Carbon::setLocale('fr')
```

method is only for the

```
->diffForHumans()
```

method.
Notice that the php setlocale() reference to the locale stored on your OS
to choose one of the installed one use

```
locale -a
```

on your console

secondly, you have to use

```
->formatLocalized()
```

method instead of

```
->format()
```

method

and lastly all the usefull methods like

```
->toDateString()
->toFormattedDateString()
->toTimeString()
->toDateTimeString()
->toDayDateTimeString()
```

are not being localized

and lastly you have to use these parsing letters

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 43):

**Translating a carbon date using global localized format**

Tested in: Laravel 5.8, Laravel 6, Laravel 8

---

In config/app.php

```
'locale' => 'id', // The default is 'en', but this time I want localize them to Indonesian (ID)
```

Then, to make locale output do something like this:

```
// WITHOUT LOCALE
Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-03-01')->format('d F Y'); //Output: "01 March 2019"
now()->subMinute(5)->diffForHumans(); // Output: "5 minutes ago"

// WITH LOCALE
Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-03-01')->translatedFormat('d F Y'); // Output: "01 Maret 2019"
now()->subMinute(5)->diffForHumans(); // Output: "5 menit yang lalu"
```

For more information about converting localize dates you can see on below link
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 19):

I configured it in the AppServiceProvider.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Localization Carbon

        \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    }
}
```