# How to set language for Carbon?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So i want to set language for Carbon, but i always get same result.

```
  Carbon::setLocale('es');
$archive_current_year = Articles::whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::now()->startOfYear(),
    Carbon::now()->endOfYear(),
  ])->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->created_at->format('F');
  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try using PHP function `setlocale` also check if your hosting allows and gives you the locales you want.

```
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
 Carbon::setLocale('es');
 $archive_current_year = Articles::whereBetween('created_at', [
 ....
```

Answer (score 4):

Carbon is actually using the php `setlocale();`. The `Carbon::setLocale('es')`
method is only for localized Carbon methods like `->diffForHumans()` method.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549845/laravel-5-carbon-global-locale), notice that the php `setlocale()` reference to the locale stored on your OS. To choose one of the installed one, type `locale -a` on your console.
Secondly, you will have to use `->formatLocalized()` method instead of `->format()` in order to use the format on the desired locale which can be found at the following link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: You should give credit to the original user when copying their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549845/laravel-5-carbon-global-locale

Answer (score 3):

In modern versions of Carbon you can get the month name localized specifiying the locale before and then with the property "monthName".

```
$date = Carbon::parse($data["Date"])
$month = $date->locale('es_ES')->monthName
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above answer didn't work for you,try using `->translatedFormat()` method for `Carbon`. `->formatLocalized()` is deprecated now.

```
 \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(app()->getLocale());
 \Carbon\Carbon::create($YOUR_DATE)->translatedFormat('M d, Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, the method [locale()](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.72.1/src/Carbon/Traits/Localization.php#L447) should be used after instance implementing  [CarbonInterface](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.72.1/src/Carbon/CarbonInterface.php) manipulations:

```php
echo now()->addWeek()->subSecond()->diffAsCarbonInterval();
// 6 days 23 hours 59 minutes 58 seconds

echo now()->addWeek()->subSecond()->locale('lt')->diffAsCarbonInterval();
// 6 days 23 hours 59 minutes 58 seconds

echo now()->addWeek()->subSecond()->diffAsCarbonInterval()->locale('lt');
// 6 dienos 23 valandos 59 minutės 58 sekundės
```