# Carbon::setLocale() not working Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I want to print the current date in Spanish with Carbon with this format: **Miércoles 31 de octubre 2018** but I only get **Wednesday 31 October 2018**.

I already used:

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
$fecha = Carbon::now()->format('l j F Y');
```

and:

```
Carbon::setLocale(LC_TIME, 'es');
$fecha = Carbon::now()->format('l j F Y');
```

In **config/app.php**, I tried with:

```
Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('es');
```

I also tried **es_ES, es_MX, es_US, es_MX.utf8** but it keeps returning the date in English. I am working on Linux and I already added the locales I need.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set language for Carbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331137/how-to-set-language-for-carbon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi use this it will works

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
echo iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', strftime("%A, %d de %B ", strtotime(Carbon::now())));
```

Answer (score -1):

try using PHP function setlocale also check if your hosting allows and gives you the locales you want.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
 Carbon::setLocale('es');
```

This is an answer given by `Eimantas Gabrielius`

Can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331137/how-to-set-language-for-carbon)