# Carbon change language to Czech

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to show date in article with `$article->created_at->diffForHumans()` and for now I am getting English language for example: 2 hours ago.

I would like to get the date in Czech language.

**What I have tried:**

By this articles: [Laravel 5 Carbon global Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549845/laravel-5-carbon-global-locale), [How to set language for Carbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331137/how-to-set-language-for-carbon)

In AppServicePrivider.php I set it up locale for Carbon.

```
`public function boot()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('cz');

}`
```

But it did not work. I also tried different language as German, Spanish and French all works except Czech.
I am using Laravel 5.6.

Comment: Did you try 'cs'? https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang/tree/master/src

Comment: ohhhh no way I would not think about CS, silly me. Thank you it work!