# Laravel Carbon set locale doesn't apply

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, locale

I have a problem to return date in french in my laravel project,

in my model I have the following method :

```
public function getShowDateAttribute()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('fr_FR');
    return Carbon::parse($this->conference_date)->format('D d F Y');
}
```

But the date is still in english,

I've tried also

```
setLocale(LC_TIME,'fr_FR');
```

But the date is still in english.
I've also tried to use the php date function and the localizedFormat method of Carbon but always same result : date in english,

would you have any idea of the problem ?
( I checked with locale -a and fr_FR is available on my computer )

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 Carbon global Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549845/laravel-5-carbon-global-locale)

Answer (score 4):

**Translating a carbon date using global localized format**

Tested in: Laravel 5.8, Laravel 6, Laravel 8

---

In config/app.php

```
'locale' => 'id', // The default is 'en', but this time I want localize them to Indonesian (ID)
```

Then, to make locale output do something like this:

```
// WITHOUT LOCALE
Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-03-01')->format('d F Y'); //Output: "01 March 2019"
now()->subMinute(5)->diffForHumans(); // Output: "5 minutes ago"

// WITH LOCALE
Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-03-01')->translatedFormat('d F Y'); // Output: "01 Maret 2019"
now()->subMinute(5)->diffForHumans(); // Output: "5 menit yang lalu"
```

For more information about converting localize dates you can see on below link
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Comment: Thanks! So the different is from `->format('d F Y')` to `->translatedFormat('d F Y')`

Answer (score 3):

So, here is the new recommended way to handle internationalization with Carbon.

```
 $date = Carbon::now()->locale('fr_FR');

 echo $date->locale();            // fr_FR
 echo $date->diffForHumans();     // il y a quelques secondes
 echo $date->monthName;           // décembre
 echo $date->isoFormat('LLLL');   // undi 10 décembre 2018 16:20
```

[For more help go here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Comment: I use carbon v1, I'll change if I can't resolve the problem but I should be able to make it with Carbon 1

Comment: Just keep in mind that Carbon 2.x version requires PHP 7.1.8+.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `fr` only while setting locale. Other looks fine

```
Carbon::setLocale('fr');
```