# Laravel - Carbon Localization Through App Locale

Tags: php, laravel, localization, php-carbon

I have an issue with localization of Carbon date outputs.

How do I tie carbon locale with my app locale? I store language preference of the user in db, and I have SetLocale middleware on entire system to check and set the locale for each user.

How do I do the same for Carbon in its entirety?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user) {
        if ($user->locale != null) {
            $locale = $user->locale;
            \App::setLocale($locale);
        } else {
            \App::setLocale('en');
        }
    } else {
        \App::setLocale('en');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I have tried adding below code, but it didn't work.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try it in `AppServiceProvider`?

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {    
        Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    }
}
```

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43031296/2693543)

Comment: I am sending some variables to Views, it's bit long but it doesn't have anything related to dates or time.