# Laravel 8 - Translate Carbon output

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How can I translate the Carbon time function on Laravel 8

For example updates_at->diffForHumans() returns something like "1 hour Ago" but I want it in another language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 Carbon global Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549845/laravel-5-carbon-global-locale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setLocale()` method , as for Spanish language :

```
@php
   \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('es');
@endphp

{{ $data->updates_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to set it in AppServiceProvider, like this (to Danish).

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // setting standar language for carbon
        \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('da');
    }
}
```